# How to use google pubsub library with scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing a Google pubsub client using the Java API, the client is written in Scala. The problem of this code is that it's not idiomatic in scala with the use of `null` and the `while true` loop

```
 val receiver = new MessageReceiver() {
      // React to each received message
      // If there are any
      override def receiveMessage(message: PubsubMessage, consumer: AckReplyConsumer): Unit = { // handle incoming message, then ack/nack the received message
        System.out.println("Id : " + message.getMessageId)
        System.out.println("Data : " + message.getData.toStringUtf8)
        throw new RuntimeException("This is just an exception")
        consumer.ack()
      }
    }

var subscriber: ApiService = null
    try { // Create a subscriber for "my-subscription-id" bound to the message receiver
      var subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build
      subscriber.startAsync
      // ...
    } finally {
      // stop receiving messages
      if (subscriber != null) subscriber.stopAsync()
    }
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

How do I tranform this code in order to use scala's Future or cats `IO`

Comment: To make it more Scala-like, start by not using mutable variables. It is bad practice to use mutable variables in Scala. Also, have you tried to do this yourself? What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Lightbend's Alpakka Google Cloud Pub/Sub connector?
https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/google-cloud-pub-sub.html

It works very well and is idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

There is a Pub/Sub Scala client in `cats` style - https://github.com/hyjay/fs2-google-cloud-pubsub

Disclaimer: I'm the author.